# SQL update multiple values in a newly added column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this database in MySQl named friends, and let's say I have three rows in the Friends table.

```
ID   Name  Age  Email(newly added column)
1    Jane  22
2   Melissa 23
3   Andrew  23
```

Now I want to add emails to each of the person in the database using this SQL syntax below, but it doesn't work. Where did I go wrong?

```
Update friends
set email= 'jane@abc.com' where id = 1,
set email= 'Melissa@abc.com' where id = 2,
set email= 'Andrew@abc.com' where id = 3;
```

Comment: Since you are using MySQL, why did you add Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server tags to your question? Answers may depend on the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do it 3 different queries like:

```
Update friends set email= 'jane@abc.com' where id = 1;
Update friends set email= 'Melissa@abc.com' where id = 2;
Update friends set email= 'Andrew@abc.com' where id = 3;
```

OR use case when expression:

```
Update friends set email= (case when id=1 then 'jane@abc.com'
                                when id=2 then 'melissa@abc.com'
                                when id=3 then 'andrew@abc.com' end)
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot Eray for clarifying, your solution works perfectly well!

Comment: Seems `case when` missing `end` keyword

Comment: Glad to help user 71812. Will appreciate if you select the answer as the correct answer by clicking the tick on the left @user71812

Answer (score 0):

Your statements are correct. Just remove the commas and run these statements separately.

```
Update friends set email= 'jane@abc.com' where id = 1;
Update friends set email= 'Melissa@abc.com' where id = 2;
Update friends set email= 'Andrew@abc.com' where id = 3;
```